# Inverse of a matrix has a special, symmetric structure

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I am solving a under-determined system of equations: $\mathbf{Ax} = \mathbf{b}$, which is fomulated from an inverse problem with certain physical backgrounds. Using Matlab, it is easy to find the minimum-norm solution with `pinv(A)`. My problem is that I find `pinv(A)` always has a certain feature. For example, when `A` is:

[image]

then, `abs(pinv(A))` is

[image]

As is shown, 1st row = 6th row, 2nd row = 5th row, and 3rd row = 4th row. This feature is universal in my problem.

Can someone tell me what analytical method can be used to mathmatically explain why `A` and `pinv(A)` have this feature?

Comment: Please consider embedding `A` and `ans` in text, rather than image, so that readers can play with your data.  No one is going to be entering data based on your images.